# Function in pygame not generating output correctly

Tags: python, function, pygame

I have a function which checks for collision

```
def collision_check1 (pboard_rect):
    if pboard_rect.colliderect(up_border_rect):
        pboard_rect = pboard.get_rect(topleft = (695,20)
        print("hi")
```

```
if game_active:
   collision_check1(pboard_rect)
```

Here it prints 'hi' but it doesn't move my `pboard_rect` what to do

edit:

```
pboard_x = 695
pboard_y = 200



pboard = pygame.image.load("data/pboard.png")
pboard_rect = pboard.get_rect(topleft = (pboard_x,pboard_y))


screen.blit(pboard,pboard_rect)
```

Comment: your call to `get_rect` is incomplete. you assign `pboard_rect` inside the function, it is a different variable compared to argument used in `collision_check1(pboard_rect)`. Do not do side effects in a function. This function `checks` and should return a `True/False`

Comment: What do I do then to change the postion of my object if it collides up_border

Comment: I havent assigned the pboard_rect in the function I mean i have assigned it earlier then to change its position i didnt know what to do so i re assigned it

Comment: the function argument is a different variable with the **SAME** name, at the start it contains the same handle, not anymore after the `pboard_rect = pboard.get_rect()`, Read the Python docs on variable **scope**

Comment: Ok then what do I do to change the location of my object if it collides with up border

Comment: Please help me @rioV8

Answer (score 1):

```
def collision_check1 (pboard_rect):
    if pboard_rect.colliderect(up_border_rect):
        print("hi")
        return pboard.get_rect(topleft = (695,20))

if game_active:
   pboard_rect = collision_check1(pboard_rect)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me and finding the error in my code

Comment: @Rice If this solves your question you can mark this answer as solution

Comment: I put this in my code and it generated a error : invali destination to blit (pboard,pboard_rect)

Comment: @Rice I can't see more code than you posted, your code was incomplete, you had an update of `pboard_rect` problem, caused by variable scope (never use global variables if possible), Examine the rect and find out what its content is and why it is illegal to blit

Comment: was the edit helpful or should I add some more details